# Summing values based on matching another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the following setup: Rank names in column A and Rank values in column C (some data in between).

Based on min and max rank I need to find the average value (I2 on the image).

My best attempt is in I3 but I have a feeling that this can be done in a nicer way.

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What about [VLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XLOOKUP to return the values for both of the ranks, then average the result array. Like this:

```
=AVERAGE(XLOOKUP($F$2:$G$2,$A$2:$A$6,$C$2:$C$6))
```

[image]

Adjust your ranges appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have Microsoft 365 Apps, you could try `=AVERAGE(VLOOKUP($F2:$G2,$A$2:$C$6,3,FALSE))` formula.

[image]

The Averageif or Averageifs functions seem not be suitable.